# laravel console command. imagecreatefromjpeg throws a fatal error if the image is corrupt

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

The below code triggers a FatalErrorException. It works as expected when run in a route, but not as an artisan command.

```
$im = @imagecreatefromjpeg(resource_path('corrupt.jpg'));

if(!$im){
    echo "corrupt image..";
}
```

[image]

I've tried catching it as an Exception and FatalErrorException but can't. Likely as it's fatal and so too late.

Comment: can't you just try/catch it in stead of suppressing the error? Can you show us that version as well?

Comment: @Pevara I've tried that, but it doesn't catch it. The output is the same.

Comment: So something like this doesn't catch the error? `try { $im = imagecreatefromjpeg(resource_path('corrupt.jpg')); } catch (\Exception $e) { echo "corrupt image.."; die(); } `

Comment: No, because it is a fatal, which is registered by laravel as a shutdown function.

Answer (score 0):

Oftentimes, the PHP-CLI and the server PHP runtime use two different `php.ini` configuration files. Also the PHP versions could be different.

So check your `phpinfo()` and compare it the PHP-CLI settings and version. This is a tough one to crack, so good luck.